# Did Palpatine know about Padmé's twins and the destruction of the Death Star through the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, darth-sidious

Somewhere on StarWars.com on [Leland Chee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leland_Chee)'s old blog, I thought I read that Palpatine knew about Padmé's twins and the destruction of the Death Star through the Force.

Where is there a source that says that?

Comment: Can you find appropriate quote from Leeland? Try Google + Wayback Machine

Comment: The only thing I have ever read was that the children were hidden from Anakin and the emperor (the jedi knew the emperor was bad by then) after birth.  Obi Wan, Yoda, and Bael Organa were the only ones who knew and they never shared the truth with anyone.

Comment: The duplicate question answers whether he knows about Luke and Leia, but not whether he knew about the Death Star being blown up.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Perhaps the question should be edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

Beyond the fact that his apprentice was infatuated with the Former Queen and Senator, Palpatine had little interest in the woman.  Palpatine was not the great planner and scientist that his master (Darth Plagueis) was.  He believed his power and destiny was to bring the galaxy under his thumb and that the force would not allow anything to foil his plans.  That Plagueis spent time worrying about and hiding from his foes was a weakness, and one that Sidious used to bring about his downfall.

For this reason Palpatine never bothered to even learn the details of Amidalas death.  That she was dead was enough for Palpatine to use to fully turn his apprentice to the dark side.

Palpatine was also not one that liked a dramatic and visible ending to his foes.  He preferred a preemptive strike long before they became a real threat.  Had Palpatine known, I suspect he would have had the children slain, and done everything he could to have Bael Organa and his family destroyed before the princess could mature and learn to use her powers.